# What is the best way of interpreting "Bit String"

Tags: c++

I was wondering what is the best way to interpret "bit string"?

for example:

a bit string like "1010010" is feed to the following function

```
void foo (string s1) {
  // some code to do bit manipulation of the bit string
}
```

What is the best way to do it? Many thanks!!!

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "interpret"? do you want to convert it into an int or do you want to do some logic depending on the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert string into its integral value, then [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family could help:

```
int value = std::stoi("10100"); //value will be 10100, not 20
```

If you want to manipulate bit patterns represented by string, then [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) might help you in some way:

```
std::bitset<32>  bitpattern("10100"); 

//you can manupulates bitpattern as you wish
//see the member functions of std::bitset

//you can also convert into unsigned long
unsigned long ul = bitpattern.to_ulong();  //ul will be 20, not 10100
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [strtol](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/stdlib.h/strtol.php)

EXAMPLE:

```
  char *endptr;
  long i = strtol (mystring, &endptr, 2);
```